# BASH : Fake two dimensional array

Tags: arrays

I have those array to simulate a two dimensional array

```
        #OC possibles values
            #d
        ocPossibleValue0[0]=1
        ocPossibleValue0[1]=2
        ocPossibleValue0[2]=5
        ocPossibleValue0[3]=10
        ocPossibleValue0[4]=15
        ocPossibleValue0[5]=20
        ocPossibleValue0[6]=30
        ocPossibleValue0[6]=200



            #t
        ocPossibleValue1[0]=0
        ocPossibleValue1[1]=5
        ocPossibleValue1[2]=10
```

if I have an index $i and $j, what I want to do is

ocPossibleValue$i[$j] to access it

however, the $i is not considered a number but a text string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it as follows:

```
arr=ocPossibleValue$i[$j]
echo ${!arr}
```

Comment: you sir are a genius! dawm I hate bash script!! but thanks a lot, you prevented me from going crazy!!!

Comment: may I ask you too if I'd like to have the size of
ocPossibleValue$i
how would it be done?

Comment: try `arr="\${#ocPossibleValue$i[@]}"` and then `eval "echo $arr"`

Comment: however I am able to display the value, but if I want it in a variable?
maybe I understand wrong, but I though eval was juste receiving a string and entering it on a command line... but my variable, I want to store this size in a variable, no matter how I do it it doesn't work?

Comment: you can always do `var=``eval "echo $arr"`` ` - use a single apostrophe here

Comment: again thank you! now I should be good!
I know I said thanks, but trust me I mean it a thousand times!!